# ServiceAuthorizationManager exception always sending xml response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have a custom ServiceAuthorizationManager implemented in wcf webhttp service to do api key verification. It sends a webfaultexception with the code 403 if the key is invalid.

But the issue is, when the exception is thrown, it s always send to the client as xml.

The service accepts both JSON and XML and it s working fine for all the other operations except for the exception from the manager.

No matter if I set the accept header or content type the result is always xml. But for other requests, the response type switches perfectly according to the content-type header

Here's the web.config

```
  <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"  />
```

Any help is really appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else ran into this issue: looks like no way to fix it. The solution I did was to do the verification in the service's constructor. Make sure the instance context mode is set to per call.

More info http://amilagm.com/2012/04/better-way-to-do-api-key-verification-in-wcf-webhttp-services/